# when using py2exe to convert into exes, yaml packages cannot be imported, while yaml works in IDLE

Tags: python, yaml, py2exe

I have installed yaml successfully, which works well python IDLE using `import yaml`. When using  py2exe to convert into exes, raise `ImportError: no module named yaml`. My setup.py as below:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
    console=[{'script': 'mutilGeo.py'}],
    options={
        'py2exe': 
        {
            'includes': ['pymongo', 'yaml']
        }
    }
)
```

Is the yaml'path cannot be found by py2exe ?  How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemd to the *YAML* is not installed successfully. As to work well in python idle, I think it may be installed by using exe program or existed in other package. When using `python setup.py install` to install the *YAML* package, it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps on your cmd:

1. `git clone https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml`
2. `cd pyyaml`
3. `python setup.py install`
4. `python setup.py --with-libyaml install`
   (Source : https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml)